# Comparing date range quarters sql server

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I have a policies in a system

```
PolRef       Start            End
POL123     22/11/2012      23/12/2014
POL212     24/09/2012      23/10/2012
POL214     23/08/2012      29/09/2012
```

I am asking a user for a reporting date, the user enters 24/10/2012 this becomes `@StartDate`

From this I derive what the quarter is by the month:

```
set @currentMonth = Month(@StartDate)

if @currentMonth = 1 or @currentMonth = 2 or @currentMonth = 3 begin set @startmonth = 1 set @endmonth = 3 end

if @currentMonth = 4 or @currentMonth = 5 or @currentMonth = 6 begin set @startmonth = 4 set @endmonth = 6 end

if @currentMonth = 7 or @currentMonth = 8 or @currentMonth = 9 begin set @startmonth = 7 set @endmonth = 9 end

if @currentMonth = 10 or @currentMonth = 11 or @currentMonth = 12 begin set @startmonth = 10 set @endmonth = 12 end
```

I then get a date range:

```
@quarterStartDate = CAST(CAST(YEAR(@StartDate) AS varchar) + '-' + CAST(@startMonth AS varchar) + '-' + '01') AS Date)

@quarterEndDate = CAST(CAST(YEAR(@EcdDate) AS varchar) + '-' + CAST(@endMonth AS varchar) + '-' + '31') AS Date)
```

This will give me 01-10-2012 and 31-12-2012. Basically I need a script to only bring back the policies that are in this quarter. The policy doesn't have to span the entire quarter date range, just exist in the quarter date range.

The results expected would be

```
PolRef       Start            End
POL123     22/11/2012      23/12/2014
POL212     24/09/2012      23/10/2012
```

Pol123 appears because it spans over the quarterly date range. Pol212 is there because it expires in that quarter date range. Pol214 does not appear because it neither spans, expires or starts in this quarter.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Uhm, what happen for june and september (ending on 30th)?

Comment: MySQL is not SQL Server.

Comment: @Steve what do you mean? Is there something I have missed?

Comment: @podiluska - Sorry added the tag as mistake

Comment: Last day of june and september is 30 not 31

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Select *
  From policies
 Where Start <= @quarterEndDate
   And @quarterStartDate <= [End]
```

If both the starts are before both the other ends, then you have an overlap (i.e. exists in quarter)

I would however drop the variables and use this more accurate range:

```
Select *
  From policies
 Where Start < dateadd(q,1+datediff(q,0,getdate()),0)
   And dateadd(q,datediff(q,0,getdate()),0) <= [End]
```

Comment: So what if a policy starts on 22/10/2012 and ends on 21/11/2012. there is value in the quarter but it will not show?

Comment: Why won't it show? `22/10/2012 < [1/1/2013] AND [1/10/2012] <= 21/11/2012` Dates in \[\] are the quarter start/ends.  Replace `Getdate()` with `@StartDate` in the query, of course.

Comment: @RichardTheKiwi: you may add sql fiddle http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/3bc47/2 to your answer

Comment: @RichardTheKiwi - My mistake, Excellent second option

Comment: @Joe Please feel free to edit the answer and add your name to it. Always good to have an SQL Fiddle link

Answer (score 0):

you may try this

```
select * from policies where start>=@quarterStartDate
 and end<=@quarterenddate
```

Comment: So what if a policy starts on 22/10/2012 and ends on 21/11/2012. there is value in the quarter but it will not show?

Answer (score 0):

```
select *
from policies
where 
    [Start] <= @quarterEndDate and
    [End] >= @quarterStartDate
```

To find start and end of quarter you can use

```
declare @date datetime, @quarterStartDate datetime, @quarterEndDate datetime

select @date = convert(datetime, convert(nvarchar(8), getdate(), 112), 112)

select @quarterStartDate = dateadd(qq, datepart(qq, @date) - 1, dateadd(dd, -datepart(dy, @date) + 1, @date))
select @quarterEndDate = dateadd(dd, -1, dateadd(mm, 3, @quarterStartDate))
```

Answer (score 0):

If startdate and enddate are dates, and not datetimes...

```
Select * 
from policies 
where StartDate<=@quarterenddate
and EndDate>=@quarterstartdate
```

You may also find `datepart(q,getdate())` useful.

To calculate quarter start and end dates

```
select @quarterstartdate = convert(varchar(4),year(@d))+'-' + CONVERT(varchar(2),(DATEPART(Q,@d))*3-2)+'-1',
       @quarterenddate= dateadd(day,-1,DATEADD(month,3, @quarterstartdate))
```